# Firefox can't connect to server ws://192.168.0.15:9000/

Tags: python, websocket

I saw that this problem is quite common, but I couldn't figure it out how to solve it in my case.
I'm creating a server in Python like this:

```
clients = []
server = None

class SimpleWSServer(WebSocket):
    def handleConnected(self):
        clients.append(self)

    def handleClose(self):
        clients.remove(self)

def run_server():
    global server
    server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 9000, SimpleWSServer,
                                   selectInterval=(1000.0 / 15) / 1000)
    server.serveforever()

t=threading.Thread(target=run_server)
t.start()

if( ...) 
            for client in clients:
                msg = json.dumps({'x': cX, 'y': cY})
                client.sendMessage(unicode(msg))
```

and I'm open a WebSocket using three.js in this way:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.15:9000/');
 ws.onopen = function() {
     console.log('onopen');
 };

 ws.onmessage = function (event) {
     var m = JSON.parse(event.data);
     history.push({ x: m.x * 2 - 1, y: -m.y * 2 + 1});
     window.alert("X: "+x + " Y "+ y)
     // ... rest of the function.
 };
```

The localhost server is created using node.js and I don't have any errors in the log, meanwhile in Google Chrome I have the error: " threejs_prova.js:3 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.0.15:9000/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response"

Error in Firefox is:

```
Firefox can't connect to server ws://192.168.0.15:9000/
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.15:9000/');
```

with

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9000/');
```

solved the problem

Comment: Since nowhere in your question did you say how you determined the IP address of your machine, this is not surprising.